# Why is the body of FD-SOI FETs undoped?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

In a conventional MOSFET, the body is doped silicon, but why is the body of FD-SOI FETs undoped?

I have come across this in multiple sources where they all state that it doesn't need to be doped because the body is very thin without explaining it. Why do we not need to dope it if the body is thin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for not doping is not really because the body is "thin", but rather, it's because the body is isolated from other devices on the same chip by the insulating oxide layer.

In non-SOI devices, the channel is formed by inverting the carrier population of the doped body, and the channel is isolated from the substrate by the reverse-biased junction formed by that. For example, in an N-channel enhancement-mode MOSFET, the body is P-doped, with an excess of holes. The channel doesn't form until the gate is brought positive enough with respect to the substrate to attract sufficient electrons immediately under it to bridge the gap between the source and the drain. Between the channel and the rest of the P-doped body, there is an "intrinsic" region that is devoid of charge carriers, isolating it from the substrate.

In the SOI devices, the body is already permanently isolated, so its doping, if any, is strictly used to control the specific characteristics of that transistor.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how does the channel form in SOI devices with undoped body?

Comment: Remember the "intrinsic" part of the channel in the non-SOI transistor? The undoped body of the SOI transistor is exactly the same thing. The channel forms when the gate attracts enough electrons right underneath it.

Comment: So is the main reason for doping the body of non-SOI devices for isolation?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, you don't get the reverse-biased PN junction.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SOI, the glass under the FET introduces ghastly thermal coefficients.

Comment: Please expand this answer, it is not long enough to be an answer